# Angular importing function from another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have a notifications.component, where's a function test(), and I have a Button in the settings.component which should call this exact function:

```
  ...
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {
  ...

  test(){
    console.log("Test NotificationsComponent interaction")
  }
}
```

I tried to import the NotificationsComponent Class into the settings.component, and made a function to call the test() function from the settings, which gets triggered by a button:

```
import { NotificationsComponent } from './../notifications/notifications.component';
...
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private notificationsComponent: NotificationsComponent,
...
    ) { }
...
  testtest(){
    this.notificationsComponent.test()
  }
}
```

When triggering the testtest() function from settings.component I get the fallowing Error:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(SettingsModule)[NotificationsComponent -> NotificationsComponent -> NotificationsComponent -> NotificationsComponent]:
```

I guess this approach is completly wrong, but i don't get why. I tried to implement several other approches like [those](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) but without success.
I'd appreciate if someone could point me in a direction to solve this problem!

Comment: This is not an ideal way of communication between components.

Comment: I thought so too, unfortunatly I'm completly clueless as where to look for a solution. Is [this](https://medium.com/@mirokoczka/3-ways-to-communicate-between-angular-components-a1e3f3304ecb) how you would make this interaction work, or is there another way?

Comment: Are these components have parent child relation or siblings?

Comment: they have no relation at all, they are both seperate components

Comment: Then i would suggest you to use a service for communication, please use this link for your understanding - https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: It's not possible to inject another component in a component this way, like Prince said you should use a Service instead.

Comment: thanks for the the link, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new service:

```
ng generate service notification
```

Add your method to that service:

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' }) export class NotificationService {

  constructor() { }

  test() {
    console.log('Test NotificationsComponent interaction');   } }
```

Inject the new service to the component you would like to use it:

```
import { NotificationsComponent } from './../notifications/notifications.component';
...
export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
...
    ) { }
...
  testtest(){
    this.notificationService.test()
  }
}
```

You can find a good article on Medium about Angular services [here](https://medium.com/@jeremy_96642/learning-angular-what-is-a-service-e4a9244e652a)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that way I got the kind of behaviour I needed!

Answer (score 0):

If that notification component is within the settings component

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { NotificationsComponent } from './../notifications/notifications.component';

export class SettingsComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild notificationsComponent: NotificationsComponent;

  constructor() { }

  testtest(){
    this.notificationsComponent.test()
  }
}
```

This will work..

Or else. Add @Injectable({providedIn:'root'}) to your NotificationsComponent

```
@Injectable({providedIn:'root'})
export class NotificationsComponent implements OnInit {

  test(){
    console.log("Test NotificationsComponent interaction")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that idea! I try your second approach as well, though the approach of having a service between them seems to work like it should, but probably that way I would not need to change that much else in the App.